# Clean Scala syntax for "Append optional value to Seq if it exists"

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I often see these two patterns for appending an Optional value to a Seq:

```
def example1(fooList: Seq[Foo], maybeFoo: Option[Foo]): Seq[Foo]) = {
  if (maybeFoo.isDefined)
    fooList :+ maybeFoo.get
  else
    fooList
}

def example2(fooList: Seq[Foo], maybeFoo: Option[Foo]): Seq[Foo]) = {
  maybeFoo match {
    case Some(foo) => fooList :+ foo
    case None => fooList
  }
}
```

Both of those methods work, but they seem verbose and ugly. Is there an existing operator or method to do this more naturally/functionally?

Thanks!

Comment: If you just want to stream line the approach you have, you can write `fooOpt.map(fooSeq :+ _).getOrElse(fooSeq)` as well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Option implicitly converts into a sequence with 1 or 0 items so the following works:

```
scala> val opt = Some("a")
opt: Some[String] = Some(a)

scala> val nope = None
nope: None.type = None

scala> val seq = Seq("a", "b", "c")
seq: Seq[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> seq ++ opt
res3: Seq[String] = List(a, b, c, a)

scala> seq ++ nope
res4: Seq[String] = List(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
maybeFoo.foldLeft(fooList)(_ :+ _)
```